# Ignore ERB in javascript with SublimeLinter-jshint

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, sublimetext3, jshint, sublimelinter

How can I make SublimeLinter-jshint ignore embedded ruby (erb) code? The following code causes the error "Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'" (and two others).

I would like SublimeLinter-jshint to ignore anything within `<%` and `%>`.

```
<script>
  <% if @foo %>
    var foo = 'bar';
  <% end %>
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

JSHint has an undocumented `ignoreDelimiters` option. To ignore erb statements, add a `.jshintrc` file to your project (or specify a global one using SublimeLinter configuration) with the following settings:

```
{
  "ignoreDelimiters": [
    { "start": "<%=", "end": "%>" },
    { "start": "<%", "end": "%>" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: any idea how you would ignore a JS object with keys pointing at a ruby erb? example:
 ` $('#foo').select2('data', { id: <%= @foo.id %>, name: '<%= @foo.name %>' });`

Comment: @ChrisCPO, I don't know. The code above works great for strings (like in your `name` variable), but it doesn't work for direct replacements (like your `id` variable). I ended up switching to ESLint.

Comment: Thanks @dignoe, combined with your answer, we ended up wrapping our erb's with an empty string, so when the linter lints the erbs were replaced with "" instead of an nil which raised an error.